# What is the rough oxygen consumption of a common garden skink?

Tags: lizards, terrariums

I've found no information online - what's the average oxygen consumption of the [common garden skink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_garden_skink)? It's a small 10cm lizard. Even a very rough estimate would be helpful.

Comment: I either don't understand what you are asking, or I can't understand why it matters.  The animal lives in room air, correct?

Comment: For research purposes I need a rough idea on how long lizards of that size can exist in a fully enclosed space, and to do this I need to know their rate of oxygen consumption.

Comment: If it's not offending, what research purposes? And how would you gather information if 1st, we don't have the equipment to do that kind of stuff nor will we probably ever do it. 2nd, the internet isn't going to have any information because no one has probably considered the idea. I would think that this question couldn't be answered because of the reasons above.

Comment: I asked the question in biology, and they redirected me here. The use of seemingly 'safe' things like Fluon and other light carcinogenic substances in reptile keeping alters reptile metabolism, especially oxygen consumption. I'd like a rough idea on the oxygen consumption of a particular lizard as a baseline to ensure particular lizards are unaffected.

Comment: This question looks like it is related to animal research not pets and would seem to fall out of scope for this site. Looking at your [biology account](http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/15224/edge) i don't see where you have asked the question. Unless it was posted and deleted there I am considering migrating this question there.

Comment: FWIW: There might not be any answer because it's a very difficult thing to study with lizards (and any other small, wild, animal) as it requires the subject to wear a mask in order to take measurements. It's also of extremely low importance in regards to pet keeping, as their other needs, such as temperature and UV light, are what will cause them harm (and they don't keep them in fully enclosed spaces).